# Grouping Column Results by Result Name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, grouping

In Snowflake, I am trying to get a specific column to group results by result names to reduce the number of duplicate rows reported. Example: instead of getting 1,227 rows in Column ItemName of "New Client Session", I would like this condensed to 1 row when all other data in the row match.

Below is the query I've constructed, but can't get to work.

```
SELECT
   StudioID,
   StudioName,
   ItemName,
   ServiceCategory,
   RevenueCategory,
   SecondRevenueCategory
FROM
   BV_SalesOverview
WHERE
   SecondRevenueCategory <> 'Null'
ORDER BY
   ItemName
```

Any ideas/options are greatly appreciated.

I've tried using `GROUP BY`, but can't seem to get it right. I continue to get errors.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please include some sample data and expected output in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of services to verify all categories and subcategories are correct. The problem is I'm getting every individual transaction for each service instead of getting a single line of data per unique item.

ROW   STUDIOID     ITEMNAME     SERVICECAT     REVENUECAT     SECONDREVCAT
1         123                New Client     Massage           Membership      Enhancement
2         123                New Client     Massage           Membership      Enhancement
3         123                New Client     Massage           Membership      Enhancement

Comment: You might want to read up on `DISTINCT`

Comment: Thank you demircioglu! That seems to be putting me on the right path.